# Sed file from row number stored in array

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've an array such

```
echo ${arr[@]}
1 13 19 30 34
```

I would like to use this array to sed rows (1,13,19,30 and 34) from other file. I know that I can use a loop, but I would like to know if there is a more straightforward way to do this. So far I've not been able to do it.

Thanks

Comment: what would you do on those rows/lines from "another file"?

Comment: Just want to split a file in two based on the array index. Array numbers are rows.

Comment: @biorunner88, that's slightly different. How that numbers `1 13 19 30 34` should help to split the file? Can you post the file?

Comment: so line# `1, 13,19...34` in one file, the rest lines in the other file?

Comment: I've an array `arr` with numbers. Those numbers stored in the array are lines that I want to extrac from a file. So I want to get rows `1, 13,19,30 and 34 ` from a file. Did I explained properly now? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***sed*** solution:

```
a=(1 13 19 30 34)
sed -n "$(sed 's/[^[:space:]]*/&p;/g' <<< ${a[@]})" file
```

This will extract 1, 13, 19, 30 and 34th rows from `file`

Comment: It seems to be doing what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a single *sed* command on each line by appending the command and a semicolon to each line, and run the result as a sed program. This can be managed in a compact way using bash pattern replacement in variables and arrays; for example, to print the selected lines, use the `p` command (`-n` suppresses printing the unselected lines):

```
sed -n "${arr[*]/%/p;}"
```

Works fine also with more complex commands like `s/from/to/`:

```
sed "${arr[*]/%/s/from/to/;}"
```

This will perform the replacement only on the selected lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v rows="${arr[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(rows,tmp); for (i in tmp) nrs[tmp[i]]} NR in nrs' file
```

Comment: Explain your solution please.

Answer (score -1):

You could use awk and the system function to run the sed command

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { system("sed -n \""$i"p\" filename") } }' <<< ${arr[@]}
```

This can be open to command injection though and so assess the risk accordingly.

Comment: I don't downvote answers @SO, however I would say, your answer deserves one.

Comment: I did downvote it. shell calling awk to call system() to call shell to call sed is crazy.